# caniuse.com is not detecting some browsers

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using the website caniuse.com. This provides compatibility tables for support of HTML5, CSS3, SVG and other technologies in various browsers.

I've imported my Google Analytics data, but 16% of my visitor stats is reported as "untracked", from "browsers not included". This includes 9% from Google.com not set and 7% from Safari 538.1.

Unfortunately this is going to skew the results.

Why is the tool only able to report on 84% of my analytics data, why are some browsers not included, and why am I getting a lot of visits from these browers (google.com not set and Safari version 538.1)?

What can I do about it to get more reliable results from the tool to help me write HTML and CSS that is compatible with my users technology?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, I suggest maybe you should ask this on [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: or maybe, even better, you can ask this to the caniuse maintainer: https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse and share the answer here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value "not set" is a placeholder that Google Analytics uses when it can't detect the value in the user agent. Google relies entirely on the agent to report details about itself. A user can fairly easily choose to hide this information or, more commonly, the user agent is a [crawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) visiting your website.

Google has a support page on "not set" [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2820717).

Safari 538.1 seems to be the user agent reported by a small open source browser project called [Otter Browser](https://otter-browser.org/). It likely does not have enough usage for caniuse to have picked up on it.

If you don't want these results in your caniuse statistics, you need to either filter your Google Analytics data beforehand, or discard the "unknown" parts in the results.